# Why should I use the node structure for a non-rigged model?

Tags: data-structures, graphics, mesh, vulkan

I'm working with Vulkan since a few weeks. I have a question about the data structure of a model:
I'm using Assimp for loading fbx and dae files. The loaded model then usually contains several nodes (RootNode and their ChildNodes).
Should I keep this structure on non-rigged models? Or could I transform all the meshes (or rather their vertices) into world space at the first loading by multiplying with the offset matrix of the node (and then delete the node structure in my program)? Because I've never seen that someone transform a node (and their meshes) after loading, if the model isn't rigged.
Or is there any other reason why I should keep this structure?

Answer (score 0):

Assimp also offers the flag `aiProcess_PreTransformVertices` to flatten the transformation hierarchy. You can also do it manually, of course, by using the `aiNode::mTransformation` matrices and multiplying them in the right order.

A potential problem with these approaches (especially with the flag) can be that the material properties of sub-meshes can get lost. Assimp doesn't care if sub-meshes have different material properties and just merges them, s.t. the material properties can get lost for a certain sub-mesh. This also applies to other properties like sub-mesh names. If sub-meshes get merged, only one (arbitrarily chosen?) sub-mesh name remains.

I.e. you'll want to prevent flattening the node hierarchy if you would like to use specific properties (names, material properties) of sub-meshes.

If your concern is only w.r.t. transforming them to world space: If you are never going to do something with the nodes in object space (like, e.g., transforming a sub-node in relation to a parent node), then I don't see a reason to not transform them into world space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would keep the sub-meshes and put them all together in the main node. So there shouldn't be a problem with the materials and names, because these variables are saved in the mesh classes. The transforming, which you described in the last sentence, is normally done by using a bone, isn't it (I've never seen that someone transforms a node without a bone)?

Comment: It doesn't have to be transformed with a bone, I think. It can just reflect the transformation hierarchy as it has been modelled in a 3D modelling tool.